# tf.reshape is not giving ?(None) for first element

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, I have tensor like below,

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

Output of `a.shape` is

> TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])

For my computational process I want to reshape the tensor to `(?, 2, 3)`

I am unable to reshape it to desire format.

I tried,

```
tf.reshape(a, [-1, 2, 3])
```

But it returns,

```
<tf.Tensor 'Reshape_18:0' shape=(1, 2, 3) dtype=int32> # 1 has to be replaced by ?
```

further I tried,

```
tf.reshape(a, [-1, -1, 2, 3])
```

it returns,

```
<tf.Tensor 'Reshape_19:0' shape=(?, ?, 2, 3) dtype=int32> # two ? are there
```

How do I get the desired result?

Sorry if it sounds simple problem.

Comment: And what is the problem? Anything that expects shape `(?, 2, 3)` should also accept shape `(1, 2, 3)`. Do you get an exception?

Comment: Yeah. I get an exception saying that the tensor has outer dimension as 1 and should  be None . This is a part of tensorflow serving model and it expects the outermost dimension to be none so that, it can provide batch outputs. if it is one, then it can provide only one output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is TensorFlow does as much shape inference as it can, which is generally something good, but it makes it more complicated if you explicitly want to have a `None` dimension. Not an ideal solution, but one possible workaround is to use a [`tf.placeholder_with_default`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default), for example like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
# This placeholder is never actually fed
z = tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.zeros([1, 1, 1], a.dtype), [None, 1, 1])
b = a + z
print(b)
# Tensor("add:0", shape=(?, 2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

Or another similar option, just with reshaping:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
s = tf.placeholder_with_default([1, int(a.shape[0]), int(a.shape[1])], [3])
b = tf.reshape(a, s)
b.set_shape(tf.TensorShape([None]).concatenate(a.shape))
print(b)
# Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(?, 2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Can you explain how it works? `z = tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.zeros([1, 1, 1], a.dtype), [None, 1, 1])` this line. especially [1, 1, 1]

Comment: @MohamedThasinah What it does is it creates a placeholder with shape `(?, 1, 1)`, with the default value `[[[0]]]`, which actually has shape `(1, 1, 1)`. Since in principle you could feed a different value for the placeholder, TensorFlow cannot assume that the actual shape is always going to be `(1, 1, 1)`, so it has to consider that the first dimension could have any size, which would result in a broadcasted addition with `a` that gives the new initial `?` dimension. The "trick" is you never actually feed a value for the placeholder, so it is like a constant with a partially unknown shape.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah That said, usually instead of doing this what you would prefer, if possible, is not check for exact shape equality, but for shape compatibility, with [`tf.TensorShape.is_compatible_with`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape#is_compatible_with).

Answer (score 0):

The task you are trying to achieve is fundamentally wrong. You are trying to make a Partially-known shape from Fully-known shape, [see the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape).

The partially-known shapes are used, when you don't know the fully-known shape during the graph construction. Anyway, you have to specify the actual shape when executing the graph. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to convert any tensor with fully-known shape to the partially-known one.

If you want to perform an operation on some partially-known shape, use broadcasting (e.g. `add` operation on tensors with shape `(1, 2, 3)` and `(None, 2, 3)` results in a tensor of shape `(None, 2, 3)`)